# WPF - How to correctly trigger edit mode in a DataGrid without a mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to set up a datagrid such that when the grid receives focus the current/selected row goes into edit mode for a specified cell. Unfortunately the row still needs a mouse click for the cell to enter edit mode.

The grid gets focus via datatrigger bound to a boolean, and this correctly triggers the GotFocus method in the code behind, which is supposed to specify the current cell and BeginEdit.

XML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SampleAliquotsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsSampleModels}}" 
                  CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentSampleAliquot, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"                   
                  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSampleAliquot, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  GotFocus="SampleAliquotsDataGrid_GotFocus"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataGridHasFocus}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=SampleAliquotsDataGrid}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Style>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RecordID" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding DBRecordID}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MeasuredResult" Binding="{Binding MeasuredResult, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="MeasuredResult" 
                                        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
               </DataGrid.Columns>                 
</DataGrid>
```

The cell to edit is the DataGridTextColumn "MeasuredResult".

the gotfocus code behind:

```
private void SampleAliquotsDataGrid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
            
            grid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(grid.SelectedItem, grid.Columns[1]);
            
            grid.BeginEdit();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

I've tried changing how the currentcell gets set, re-focusing on the grid before calling BeginEdit, changing the selection unit to Cell instead of fullrow.

Hopefully the solution isn't too complicated, my skills with WPF aren't sophisticated.

Comment: Your goal is not clear. What is the expected behavior when the `DataGrid` get focus on click in a new row. Does the edit mode should be triggered then on the selected row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the behavior bellow:

- When a cell is clicked on the selected row, the behavior of the `DataGrid` is unchanged.
- When a cell is clicked on a not select row, its row is selected and the cell in the `AutoEditColumn` is set in edition mode.
- When the `DataGrid` gain focus from keyboard (tab navigation), the cell in the `AutoEditColumn` and selected row is set in edition mode.

To achieve this, one can listen on the `CurrentCellChanged` event.
Here a helper class that implement the described behavior :

```
private class AutoEditColumnHelper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DataGrid _dataGrid;
    private readonly int _columnIndex;

    private object? _lastItem;

    public AutoEditColumnHelper(DataGrid dataGrid, int columnIndex)
    {
        _dataGrid = dataGrid;
        _columnIndex = columnIndex;

        _dataGrid.CurrentCellChanged += OnCurrentCellChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dataGrid.CurrentCellChanged -= OnCurrentCellChanged;
    }

    private void OnCurrentCellChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentCell = _dataGrid.CurrentCell;

        if (!currentCell.IsValid || Equals(currentCell.Item, _lastItem))
            return;

        var autoEditColumn = GetAutoEditColumn();
        if (autoEditColumn is null)
            return;

        _dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, () =>
        {
            _lastItem = _dataGrid.SelectedItem;
            _dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(_lastItem, autoEditColumn);
            _dataGrid.BeginEdit();
        });
    }

    private DataGridColumn? GetAutoEditColumn()
    {
        return _columnIndex < 0 || _columnIndex > _dataGrid.Columns.Count ? null : _dataGrid.Columns[_columnIndex];
    }
}
```

To use this class, [`AttachedProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/attached-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0) are the recommended way.

First, we declare a public `AutoEditColumn` attached property that store the `AutoEditColumn` index in an `int`.
Then, we declare a private `AutoEditColumnHelper` attached property that store an instance of the `AutoEditColumnHelper` below for each `DataGrid` that have a `AutoEditColumn` property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoEditColumnProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoEditColumn", typeof(int), typeof(DataGridEx), new PropertyMetadata(default(int), AutoEditColumnChangedCallback));

public static void SetAutoEditColumn(DependencyObject element, int value)
{
    element.SetValue(AutoEditColumnProperty, value);
}

public static int GetAutoEditColumn(DependencyObject element)
{
    return (int)element.GetValue(AutoEditColumnProperty);
}

private static void AutoEditColumnChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (d is not DataGrid dataGrid)
        return;

    GetAutoEditColumnHelper(dataGrid)?.Dispose();

    if (e.NewValue is int columnIndex)
    {
        SetAutoEditColumnHelper(d, new AutoEditColumnHelper(dataGrid, columnIndex));
    }
    else
    {
        d.ClearValue(AutoEditColumnHelperProperty);
    }
}


private static readonly DependencyProperty AutoEditColumnHelperProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoEditColumnHelper", typeof(AutoEditColumnHelper), typeof(DataGridEx), new PropertyMetadata(default(AutoEditColumnHelper)));

private static void SetAutoEditColumnHelper(DependencyObject element, AutoEditColumnHelper value)
{
    element.SetValue(AutoEditColumnHelperProperty, value);
}

private static AutoEditColumnHelper? GetAutoEditColumnHelper(DependencyObject element)
{
    return element.GetValue(AutoEditColumnHelperProperty) as AutoEditColumnHelper;
}
```

Finally the `AutoEditColumn` attached property is used in the `xaml` code:

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          so71475662:DataGridEx.AutoEditColumn="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Label}" Header="Label" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Value" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Full working example is available [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_71475662).

Comment: Thanks, this looks really great, unfortunately I'm hitting an error with the _dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.
I'm getting error "Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority' to 'System.Delegate'"

Some googling suggests it is because I lack a reference to System.Windows.Presentation.dll, so I downloaded this but when I attempt to add it as a project reference I get the error "The reference is invalid or unsupported"
I'm using netcoreapp3.1 v9, and visual sudio 2019

Comment: Try to remove the `DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle` parameter or to update your project to .Net6

Comment: Removing the parameter worked, thank you so much

Comment: your solution works great but for some reason on ending the edit you have to press enter twice, or click another field or command on the page twice before the cell loses focus.

I suspect it may have to do with the fact that instead of a simple `DataGridTextColumn ` element as I have in my question and you show in your solution I accidentally left it as a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, like the first column in my question. But if I change it, the solution stops working.

Any ideas how I can fix this? If not I'll set it up as another question. Thanks again for your help, it was amazing.

Comment: I think it's more related to the `DispatcherPriority`, I set it as low as possible to avoid messages crisscross. I don't really understand why you can't apply it. Does your `.csproj` file looks like the one visible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53491840/361177) ?

Comment: Make sure you have this: `using System.Windows.Threading;` and flip the parameters (delegate, then priority), it's [this extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherextensions.begininvoke?view=windowsdesktop-3.1#system-windows-threading-dispatcherextensions-begininvoke(system-windows-threading-dispatcher-system-action-system-windows-threading-dispatcherpriority))

Comment: Changing the dispatcher parameter order stops me getting the error, but adding the priority back in doesn't change the behaviour I'm seeing. My `.csproj` looks like that except I don't have an `AssemblyName`.

Comment: The actual behaviour goes like this: on pressing enter or clicking on another range/command button on the same page, the active row is unselected, the datagrid `CellEditEnding` and `LostFocus` events both appear to fire, but the cell still shows the cursor and is able to be edited, then pressing enter again (or clicking another element again) then changes focus to that element or triggers that command.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. See my git hub repo. When I click the dummy button, the behavior is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, there must be some unusual interaction going on. Possibly with events attached to the grid source items. I'll look there next.